# Symfony 2: Build own DB access layer

Tags: database, symfony, pdo, doctrine, overriding

I'm new here and on a research trip. We would like to use Symfony2 for a new project.

Now we have the problem that we need to use a company wide self-developed DB access layer.
We don't want to lose the whole Symfony/Doctrine layer for handling data.
Our idea is now to create or overwrite database access layer below Doctrine.
Something like creating a bridge (like PDO) between Doctrine and our DB access layer.

Has anyone an idea how we can do this or maybe someone has done similar things already and can provide us with an how-to?

Please no questions why. We just have to use the company access layer!
Thank you

http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=37637

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in Doctrine2 doc. It's pretty easy.

I needed for development and testing (frontend and console) about half a day

I've done it in 4 steps:

1. copy Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\OCI8 to a new folder.
2. rename files.
3. change functions to use own database access layer.
4. add in config file

```
    doctrine:
      dbal:
        driver_class: /Path/To/Driver/Class
```

Doctrine has not much but a bit of information about Abstraction Layer:
[Supporting Other Databases](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/dbal/2.1/en/reference/supporting-other-databases.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you believe [this § of the doctrine documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/introduction.html#doctrine-2-packages), you can see that you may use the `Common` package because it does not require the DBAL. Sadly, the same thing cannot be said of the ORM package. The best thing to do is probably to fork this package so that it supports your own DBAL.
Condolences for being obliged to use this DBAL.